# Jquery slider, slides doesnt go full width if parent is display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I"m making a script for a portfolio. when you click on one of the portfolio items a div will appear with the jquery onclick function like this:

```
$('#portfolioItem').click(function() {
    $('#divThatWillApear').show();
```

This all works fine. I also downloaded a slider called glide.js. this slider also work fine.

But as soon as I combine my script and the slider togheter the slider is acting wierd.

I've created a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/skunheal/fzftX/2/

the slides dont scale to the full width of the slider. but when you rescale the window they do. when I remove the display none from my parent element (portfolioOverlay) it suddenly works all fine...

any one has an idea whats going wrong and how to fix it?

Hope to hear from anyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy fix would be to initialize the slider after clicking show, to fix this problem.

```
$('#show').click(function () {
    $('#portfolioOverlay').show();
    $('.slider').glide();
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fzftX/4/)

Comment: gonna use this for now! thanx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `.slider` width is messing up as the width of the `display:none;` parent.

I "fixed" it by adding to your `.slider`

```
width: 100%;
```

to

```
width: 500px; // same as parent element, this means you are joining the width to the width of the parent however
```

Updated jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cB3Pn/

Comment: heey thanx! well I would like to keep the 100% because this way its responsive without using any javascript.

Comment: @Merijndk I hear you, but I noticed your parent was set to a fixed width.

Comment: yeah I understand. I really appriciate it!

Answer (score 1):

As the `portfolioItem` is `display:none` on load it's size/position can not be calculated by your code. Removing the `display:none` CSS and adding the following to the bottom of your JavaScript will fix this as it will hide the **portfolioItem** once the JavaScript has run.

```
$('#portfolioOverlay').hide();
```

Comment: well yeah I tought of this option but to me it felt like a work around and not a real fix. Still thanx for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the resize event yourself after showing the slider:

```
$('#show').click(function() {
   $('#portfolioOverlay').show();
   $(window).resize();
});
```